# 5 Log instances in one console Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, console, serilog

i made a class where i make 5 loggers.
Why?

Cause every logger is for a different component and logs in a different file.
But they also logg all 5 in console and it gives verry strange views

this is the code:
[image: code]

this is the view that is created after logging a few lines.
the console is fullscreen.

[image: console view]

As you can see the lines are getting mixed into each other and its messing it big time.
Is there a way to fix to problem or am i doing it completly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by adding a theme to the console.

[image: solution]